# Do logging handlers use separate threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, handlers

Python's [logging handlers](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html) are great. Some of them, such as the [SMTPHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler) may take a long while to execute (contacting an SMTP server and all). Are they executed on a separate thread as to not block the main program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SMTPHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler) uses [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html?highlight=smtplib#module-smtplib) and when sending an email with this library, your process is blocked until it have been correctly sent, no thread created.

If you do not want to block your process when sending an email, you'll have to implement your own SMTPHandler and override the `emit(self, record)` method.

The less blocking handler is the [SysLogHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html?highlight=sysloghandler#logging.handlers.SysLogHandler), because it is in general a local communication, and in UDP so the system doesn't wait for any acknowledgement from the destination.

Comment: I've added a [follow-up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591567/catch-sysloghandlers-output) question based on your input

Answer (score 0):

No, you should spawn a separate process, as far as I know.