# Catch SysLogHandler's output

Tags: python, logging, connection, multiprocessing, handlers

Following [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8591033/348545), I'm planning to log errors from several time critical python processes (clients) to a single logging process (server). [SysLogHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#sysloghandler) seems to be the correct choice as it uses UDP (I rather be system-agnostic) and does not wait for any confirmation, and as I'm using `localhost` so there should practically be no loss of logs.

However, I'm unclear as to how I should implement the server side on two accounts:

- Should I simply [open a `multiprocessing.connection`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.connection) and `conn.recv()` the log as text?
- Is there a way to handle the error as a log on the server side, thus printing it using other `logging.handlers`? Or is it just plain strings at that point?

A nice use-case would be for the time critical processes to send errors to the logging process which in turn would use [SMTPHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler) to send these errors via email...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to continue with advices ( ;) ), take a look to [rsyslog](http://rsyslog.com/), this is the most powerfull syslog server I know. 
It support threaded logging facilities, massive load and [mail sending](http://rsyslog.com/doc/ommail.html).

Comment: I was kinda hoping for something like "yeah it's a string so just send it via [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html) and be done with it". But I guess I'll have to learn yet another system... :)